# Chaining Queueables: Does the second job count against the shared limit for asynchronous Apex method executions

Tags: queueable-apex

When you are chaining Queueables: Does the second job count against the shared limit for asynchronous Apex method executions.  I am trying to reduce our number of jobs as we are nearing our asynchronous execution limit, and I'm wondering how best to consolidate my future methods. If I were to chain seven jobs together would that count as seven against the asynchronous Apex method execution limit?

Answer (score 2):

Every call to a future method, every execute method (Schedulable, Batchable, and Queueable), and every Batchable start and finish method each count against the shared limit. As such, **yes**, seven chains would result in seven counts against the daily asynchronous limit.